# Cannot enable desktop effects on an hp dv2000

Tags: 10.10, drivers, compiz

I have a laptop Hp dv2000. I recently install ubuntu 10.10. I also install the compiz fusion and update Desktop effects could not be enabled.

When I change the preference appearance visual effect it shows "Desktop effects could not be enabled" this message. How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Please accept [the answer provided by @ThomasWard](http://askubuntu.com/a/36620/18887) if it satisfies as the answer you were looking for. If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Likely you cannot enable Desktop Effects because your graphics card's drivers aren't installed.

Do the following:
**Access the Hardware Drivers tool.**  This tool (in 10.04) is found in the top panel for GNOME at **System > Administration > Hardware Drivers**.

Make sure you install the recommended driver for your graphics card.

Then reboot, and see if you can enable desktop effects.